# Where can I find filings for OTC stocks?

Tags: stock-markets, pink-sheets

If a US stock is traded on a major exchange, its filings can be found at https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/legacy/companysearch.html

Is there a place where I can find filings done by stocks on the OTCBB / pink sheets?

Note: I know I can go to the company's website, but I'm looking for a 3rd party regulatory source if there is one.

Answer (score 3):

OTCMARKETS.com lists financial report filings by date

Comment: A question / an answer / Can this be the net?   WWW Haiku

Comment: Could you include the specific URL link within Otcmarkets.com. I was browsing that site and I don't see where they list financial report filings by date.

Comment: Also, do you know if there is a way to find it by ticker symbol or company name?

Comment: Enter a quote and there's a list of filings below.   On the page there's also an icon called MENU.

Comment: This is getting pretty old but... Now if you put a ticker in the quote box you'll get an information page and there is a "Disclosure" tab/section that has filings and disclosures. The interface is not great.

Answer (score 0):

- If the stock has SEC filings, you can find the filings on [EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html). Note that all OTCBB securities have to make SEC filings, but not all OTCQX, OTCQB, OTC Pink securities have to.
- If the stock does not file with the SEC, it could have made some filings available to [OTC Markets](https://www.otcmarkets.com) under various reporting standards (see: [OTC Markets Reporting Standards](https://www.otcmarkets.com/learn/reporting-standards)). If the OTC stock in question is on the OTCQX or OTCQB tier, you are in luck, because companies on these tiers will have filings available. For OTC Pink stocks, some will have filings available on the OTC Markets' website, but some do not.
- If you still can't find any documents, check the company's website. Some companies have helpful investor relations webpages.
- If the company is in a highly regulated industry, some financial information may be available from industry regulators. For example, you can find financial information about individual banks from the Federal Reserve and the FDIC.
- If you still can't find any documents, you could always contact the company to ask for information.
- If all that fails, you may have to conduct an intense research on your own.